# Downloading file in node using GridFS in production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an express app, which works when I run it locally. The issue is when downloading a file which as saved in mongoDB using GridFS. When running it locally (I just do ./bin/www and go to localhost:3000), I can download the file. But when I run it remotely, I download an html file.

This is the route which handles the response:

```
router.get('/getfile',function(req,res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
    {
            var gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection, mongoose.mongo);
            var id = req.query.id;
            gfs.exist({_id: id}, function (err, found) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                if (!found)
                    res.send('Error on the database looking for the file.')
            });

            var readStream = gfs.createReadStream({
                _id: id
            }).pipe(res);
    }
    else
        res.redirect('/login');
});
```

and that is called by this line in a jade file:

```
td #[a(href="getfile?id=#{log.videoId}" download="video") #[span(name='video').glyphicon.glyphicon-download]]
```

On the server, I'm doing:

```
/logApp$ export NODE_ENV=production
/logApp$ ./bin/www
```

the mongoDB deamon is running. In fact, I can query the database. And I'm not writing any file! I want to read it.

#### EDIT: I found the error message:

```
MongoError: file with id #### not opened for writing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code that pipes the file to the response into the `gfs.exist` callback so that it runs after the exist check.

```
gfs.exist({ _id: id }, function(err, found) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(err); 
      return;
    }

    if (!found) {
      res.send('Error on the database looking for the file.')
      return;
    }

    // We only get here if the file actually exists, so pipe it to the response
    gfs.createReadStream({ _id: id }).pipe(res);
});
```

Apparently you get that generic "not opened for writing" error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: It works, but now it hangs when making the exists request. I get no answer. gfs gets build, the _id is there, but gfs.exist call just hangs. It doesn't even produce an error. Nevertheless that's another question I guess. You indeed noticed my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the `handleError` function doesn't do anything helpful and just eats the error? Also, maybe let it hang for like 30 seconds to rule out the possibility of just an ultra-long timeout allowance heh.

Comment: No, is something else. I commented that, added console.log prints all over. I think I have something off in how I saved the files. I think I'll go through the manual and post another question if I cannot find anything...